# How to pass fuzz logic in head http for perl?

Tags: perl, http, methods, head, fuzzing

I want to fuzz http parameters using perl, how to do that, please view my sub code.

I have tried method using head but I'm getting error.

Code from line 620 to 624.

```
sub print_fuzz_methods( ) {
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20130401 Firefox/31.0.");
print color("BOLD RED"), "\n\n                              my $res = $ua->head( $url );
my $response = $browser->get(
  '$url',
  'Referer' =>  "<SCRIPT>alert('document.domain='+document.domain)</SCRIPT>",
);
```

Error:
Can't call method "get" on an undefined value at tishna.pl line 621,  line 1

Comment: Did you copy your code correctly? Looks like you're missing a closing quote `"` on line 4.

Comment: You're calling method `get` on `$browser` ... but no `$browser` variable has been defined anywhere. So, yeah, it's trying to "_call method "get" on an undefined value..._".  Seems that that `$browser` should really be `$ua`...

Comment: In the call to `get` (once you fix it to be called on `$ua`) you don't want the single quotes around `$url`. That variable need be evaluated (to the URL string), what can't happen under `''`.

Comment: You got responses for the code you posted, to fix errors (and to employ good practices).   But as for "fuzz" testing, I don't see how the question connects with that topic (except for mentioning it)? I think that there are modules for that (or that provide for it), search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that you do not have `use strict` turned on in your code. This is a mistake. The vast majority of experienced Perl programmers will recommend starting all of your Perl code with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

as these additions will tell you about a huge number of silly mistakes that programmers commonly make.

One of the most important things that `use strict` does is to force you to declare your variables. This prevents errors like the one you seem to have made here.

You create an LWP::UserAgent object in a variable called `$ua`. You then try to use that object in a variable called `$browser`. You are using the inconsistant variable names.

(It's also worth pointing out that variables are not expanded in single-quoted strings - so you want `$ua->get($url, ...)`, not `$ua->get('$url', ...)`.)